# An inductive limit of amenable groups is amenable

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, topological-groups, amenability

It is a Theorem that an inductive Limit of amenable Groups is amenable.
Could someone sketch me a proof of this, or give me a reference? I couldn't find one.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I wanted it for a directed Limit over a directed poset, not just a totally ordered one.

Comment: The proof is straightforward using the characterization by fixed points.

Answer (score 2):

This is Theorem 3.4 in [A Survey of Amenability Theory for Direct-Limit Groups](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.0185.pdf). If you are interested in arbitrary colimits, see also Theorem 3.3 (3).

Comment: great thanks. and sorry that I used the terminology "inductive Limit" instead of "directed colimit" (as you would prefer, but I use "inductive Limit" only because it is very common).

Comment: Btw I see now that the case presented there is too special.. I have thus edited the question